# VueJS Select Multiple Array Undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Eu tenho uma `Rest API` que me retorna `CategoriaList` e `CategoriaSelected`.
Ele está dando conflito quando faço com um `Select Multiple` no `HTML`

**Categorias.vue**

```
<template>

<select multiple class="form-control" v-model="dataItem.CategoriaSelecionada">
      <option v-for="item in dataItem.CategoriaList" v-bind:value="item">{{item.Name}}</option>
</select>

</template>

<script>
export default {

  data: () => ({
    dataItem: {}
  }),

  created(){

    getCategoria(){
       axios.get( localhost:61110/api/categoria )
          .then ( res => {
             this.dataItem = res.data.Data 
          })

  }    
}
</script>
```

**JSON da API**

```
Data: {
  CategoriaList: [
    { "Name": "Categoria 1", "Value": 1 }, 
    { "Name": "Categoria 2", "Value": 2 }
  ],
  CategoriaSelecionada: []
}
```

**ERRO CONSOLE**

> **[Vue warn]: select multiple v-model="dataItem.CategoriaSelecionada" > expects an Array value for its binding, but got Undefined**

Eu joguei no `HTML` um `H1` do `this.dataItem` e os valores vem certo, tanto é que o `v-for option do select` é populado, mas porque o `dataItem.CategoriaSelecionada` vem como `undefined` se ele vem da API como um `array`?

Obrigado!

**@EDIT - Resolvido**

Eu tive que inicializar no **Data** o CategoriaSelecionada como um array vazio. Aparentemente a lentidão que a API demora pra trazer os dados, acaba afetando quando o Vue desenha a DOM.

```
data: () => ({
    dataItem: {
        "CategoriaProdutoSelected": []
    }
})
```

Comment: Obrigado pela edição, @Rafael Augusto